# Is is possible to have text placeholders inside a form field (as to prompt the end user to insert a specific format) without the use of javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So basically, the website is javascript free. No javascript at all. Will not be adding javascript.

However, we need to prompt the end user to enter information accordingly to be used in a database that will then connect to software on the network.

As in, there are 2 hyphens preinserted into a form field for a telephone number.  This will prompt the user to enter 310-555-5555 instead of 3105555555.

*** I am a translator for a website owner and a web developer. I am not a programmer. I need a simple answer. I dont need you to explain how to do it. I just need to find out if the programmer is capable or if the website owner is asking for something impossible.

Comment: I think you need https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.pattern but don't know how well this is implemented in current browsers

Comment: Seems pretty unlikely to be able to modify an input string without using JavaScript. I'm inclined to say that this is _not_ possible...

Answer (score 0):

For modern browsers the HTML attribute `placeholder` already exists and does exactly what you mentioned.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder Browser support is pretty strong nowadays

Side notes that may not be needed after you further clarified you wouldn't be doing the work:

With that said it gets a little bit more involved if you want to have all users get that information and see it (this is in regards to accessibility). Also placeholders disappear after a user starts typing. Not sure if that is an issue.

Having the explanation part of the label  as well (styled differently) will make it always visible and readable by different user interaction.

Comment: Well, I wasnt even aware that placeholder was actually a coding word in HTML. I couldnt think of another to describe it. Coincidental.

Comment: However, the website owner actually wants the text to be there while typing. Maybe the user enters 310 and then skips over the hyphen 555 and skips over 5555. So the user is just typing numbers but the hyphens are still inserted. Must this be javascript? (This is what the hired programmer is saying.)

Comment: If you want the area inside of a single input to have hyphens that are forever in the input and then jumped over as a user fills out the field sounds a lot like Javascript. It's asking for functionality that isn't built into any browsers, which means extending with Javascript.

If you didn't mind having multiple input fields you could split them into 3 separate inputs and have hyphen text between them. The user would have to manually switch between the inputs. Then on the back end before submitting to the database the programming would need to combine the inputs into one string.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is absolutely possible. There are HTML placeholder attributes available which will do your job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `placeholder` attribute to prompt the user to insert a specific format and `pattern` attribute to validate the pattern entered.

```html
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="\d{3}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```